# webconfig is replaced every minute automatically

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, app-config

My requirement is to update the appsettings file at run time when the application is started. But encountered with a problem where web config is getting replaced every minute with the new appsettings. How can I stop replacing every minute?

I have gone through different solutions here and implemented as below:

1. In web config we have default path for appsettings:

```
 appSettings file="C:\Config\MyProj\Appsettings.Config"
```

2. In the Global.asax.cs, I am calling the following method to replace the my appsettings file dynamically.

```
    public void ChangeAppSettings(string path)
    {
        System.Configuration.Configuration configuration = null;
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            configuration =
                System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        }
        else
        {
            configuration =
                ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        }
        // update appconfig file path
        configuration.AppSettings.File = path;

        // Save the configuration file.
        configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

        // Force a reload in memory of the changed section.
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
    }
```

Or is there a better way to implement?

Comment: Can you provide more information about why this behavior is needed? Why not use a database to persist these application settings? And leave the static ones to .config files.

Comment: We have five environments and every environment has its own app settings and also some in common. Each environment has one Web application and one console application which share the same app settings. When we deploy it is tedious to update all the config individually. We came up with a solution where each project folder will have an environment variable which tells to pick up right app settings file. And when the application is started gets the environment path of appsettings and loads accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code did the trick, for somereason every time we refresh the config ChangeAppSettings method is called. So I just added to check if the config is already modified then don't refresh anymore.

```
if (!path.Equals(configuration.AppSettings.File))

{
    // update appconfig file path

    configuration.AppSettings.File = path;

    // Save the configuration file.

    configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

    // Force a reload in memory of the changed section.

    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

}
```